# Error: connection not open on send()

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs

I'm using Web3.js and am trying to monitor the Ethereum mainnet.  Up until now I have been testing on a local environment, but I want to test it live now.  Here's the relevant code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
let web3

if (!config.PROJECT_SETTINGS.isLocal) {
    web3 = new Web3(`wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`) 
    // web3 = new Web3(`wss://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`)
} else {
    web3 = new Web3('ws://127.0.0.1:7545')
}

// Other stuff happens

module.exports = {
    web3,
    // It exports other stuff too, but this is what matters for the question.
}
```

As you can see, when a setting `isLocal` is set to false, it should begin pulling data from an API key.  However, I continue to receive the error in the subject line.  Here's the full error log:

```
/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:66
        const error = new Error(msg);
                      ^

Error: connection not open on send()
    at Object.ConnectionError (/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:66:23)
    at Object.ConnectionNotOpenError (/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:49:21)
    at /Users/Me/bot/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:155:37
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onClose (/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:154:27)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onConnectFailed (/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:219:14)
    at WebSocketClient.<anonymous> (/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:59:25)
    at WebSocketClient.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ClientRequest.handleRequestError (/Users/Me/bot/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:227:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 1006,
  reason: 'connection failed'
}
```

I have seen from other similar posts that simply refreshing the API key is enough to make this work.  However, I have tried multiple API keys from Infura and Alchemy.  Each time, I have received the same error message.

Any other ideas about why this might be failing?

Comment: No idea if bumping works anymore, but I'm bumping in hopes of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue here.

Changed `` web3 = new Web3(`wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`) ``

To `` web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || `wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`) ``

Answer (score 0):

Ok If You want to use WebSocket Connection in web3js try using

`new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(your_WSS_Url_Here)`;

Comment: Thanks for the thought!  Unfortunately didn't work.  Same error. I even tried HttpProvider as well (using a https URL of course) and that failed as well.